# Given a complete graph with injective weight function, the $n-2$ most heaviest edges are not in any MST

Tags: graphs, minimum-spanning-tree

Let $G=(V,E)$ be an undirected complete graph, where $|V|=n,|E|=m$.
Let $w:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ be an injective weight function.

Prove that for any MST, the $n-2$ most heaviest edges are not in the MST.
I thought about proving by contradiction; assuming such MST can exist, and then replacing its heaviest edge with a lighter one, thus getting a spanning tree of lighter weight, but I got stuck there.

Comment: Do you know any algorithm for computation of MST?

Comment: @VladislavBezhentsev Kruskal and Prim. kruskal seems like the approach, because it sorts the edges by weight, but I didn't have a lead with it

Comment: Try to think about Prim algorithm instead. How much choices do you have on each iteration? Can you avoid taking one of the $n-2$ heaviest edges on each iteration?

Comment: Got it. For the first edge we got $n-1$ choices. For the second we have $2(n-2)$. For the $k$ we have $k(n-k)$. Anyway, in any iteration we have more choices than $n-2$, and we take the minimal one, so we won't take one of the $n-2$ heaviest ones. Thanks!